# Why doesn't relay call renderFailure if network requests timeout?

Tags: relayjs

I've got a `renderLoading` function that shows a spinner. I've also got a `renderFailure` function that contains a button to let a user retry a failed request. Finally, my network layer is configured with timeouts and retry delays:

```
fetchTimeout: 10000,
retryDelays: [1000, 2000, 4000, 8000, 8000],
```

If I take my local graphql server offline and and load my app, the loading spinner spins. If I start my server, within a few seconds, data is loaded, so the retries are working.

However, if I only do 2 retries (`retryDelays: [1000, 2000]`), take my server offline, reload my app and wait, the loading spinner is never replaced by the retry button I've got in my `renderFailure` function. If I bring my server back online, no data is loaded, which shows that no retries are taking place, as expected.

Is this a bug or am I missing something? Why doesn't relay call `renderFailure` (which I've tested separately and it works) if all network requests timeout and there are no more retries to try?

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce it, are you adding it to the `RootContainer`. This is working for me (https://gist.github.com/guzart/5bea8f1ac6c884d4494d)

Comment: In your description, you mention `renderFailure` and `renderFailed`. One of these is a typo. Is the typo also present in your code?

Comment: Type in my question.